# Can I disable one channel of IDE controller?

Tags: windows, registry, driver

There's one ATA channel of my IDE controller goes yellow mark.
Is there any way to disable it?
I know vendor driver may solve it, but if it is possible to disable it?
I want the whole channel to disappear. Should I edit registry or something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the ATA channel and select Disable.  It will get a red X through it.  If you want it back later, right click again and Enable it.

Comment: I mean disappear that channel. Sorry I might not use "Disable". Right-click disable will be enable again after restart. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No, you can't remove it completely from the OS.  You might try to see if you can disable it in BIOS.  But no, disabling it will not reenable it after a reboot.  It will stay disabled.